# Checking whether element is in ManyToMany field in Django

Tags: python, html, django, manytomanyfield

Hi so I have an attend session button that when clicked adds the user to the session. I got it working but I want to add a check to see whether the user is already in the ManyToMany field of attendees before I add them. How would I go about doing that?

Here is my view for it

```
def attend_session(request):

    session = Study.objects.get(pk=request.POST['session_id'])
    stud = Student.objects.get(student_user=request.user)

    if request.method == "POST":
        # Add check here to see if student is already attending
        session.attendees.add(stud)
        session.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('study:sessions'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check with:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect

def attend_session(request):
    session = get_object_or_404(Study, pk=request.POST['session_id'])
    stud = get_object_or_404(Student, student_user=request.user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if stud not in session.attendees.all():
            session.attendees.add(stud)

    return redirect('study:sessions')
```

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.

---

> **Note**: You can make use of [**`redirect(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) instead
> of first calling [**`reverse(…)`** <sup>[Django]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.reverse) and
> then wrap it in a [**`HttpResponseRedirect`** object <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect).
> The `redirect(…)` function does not only offer a more convenient signature to do this, it also for example will use the
> [**`.get_absolute_url()`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_absolute_url)
> if you pass it a model object.